# Nokogiri and isolating select elements from an array full of Nokogiri nodes

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape http://www.ign.com/games/reviews using Nokogiri and I'd like to instantiate new review objects that correspond to each game review on the page. Naturally, I'd also like to grab each numeric Score from each review and assign that score value as a class attribute to my review objects.

The problem is, the best I can do is return an entire string of scores mushed together instead of a list consisting of each score.

```
class VideoGameReviews::Review
  attr_accessor :name, :score, :url

  def self.scrape_titles
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.ign.com/games/reviews?"))

    @doc.search("#item-list div.itemList div.itemList-item").each do |review|
      new_review = VideoGameReviews::Review.new

      new_review.score = review.search("span.scoreBox-score").text
      => "99996.37.17.17.17778.58.58.586.36.47.187.57.88.95.587.6" #Not what I want
    end
  end

end
```

Any advice on how to extract a list of scores with each score separate and unique from other scores? Maybe use a more specific CSS selector?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nokogiri` properly but need to revise your logic to store the scores properly. For instance, we can get the score for an individual game pretty easily:

```
new_review.score = fourth_item.search("span.scoreBox-score").text
=> "6.3"
```

Instead of having to do everything in a single method, you can start by breaking your code into smaller methods and cacheing values as needed. I would change this class name as well since your `Review` class both represents a `Review` item and also scrapes (violation of Single Responsibility Principle). Maybe something like the following would be better?

```
require ‘nokogiri’

class VideoGameReviews::ReviewScraper

  def reviews
    @reviews ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.ign.com/games/reviews?"))
  end

  def review_items
    @review_items ||= reviews.search("#item-list div.itemList div.itemList-item")
  end

  def store_reviews
    review_items.each do |review|
      new_review = VideoGameReviews::Review.new #Review class still  used to save review
      new_review.score = review.search("span.scoreBox-score").text
      #get other data
      new_review.save! #or however you plan on persisting the data
    end
  end

end
```

The question will be:  how will you save the reviews (in local memory, in a db, etc)? For something quick, `ActiveRecord` is pretty simple (and you use it independently from Rails).

Note that the :each method in Ruby will always return the original collection on which it's called. so for instance the following will return `[1,2]`:

```
[1,2].each do |n|
  n * 4
end
```